# What is the return type of executeScript() method of JavascriptExecutor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

If a JavaScript on a web page return non-decimal value then what will `javascriptExecuter.executeScript()` will return?

Ccan anyone answer this question?

Comment: You can get that information from here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### executeScript()

[executeScript()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) executes a *JavaScript* in the context of the currently selected frame or window. The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of an anonymous function.

If the script has a return value (i.e. if the script contains a return statement), then the following type of objects are returned:

- For an HTML element, this method returns a *WebElement*
- For a decimal, a *Double* is returned
- For a non-decimal number, a *Long* is returned
- For a boolean, a *Boolean* is returned
- For all other cases, a *String* is returned.
- For an array, a *List* is returned with each object following the rules above. *Nested lists* are also supported.
- For a map, a *Map* is returned with values following the rules above.
- If the value is null or there is no return value, *null* is returned

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer this is a very enlightening article!