# Selenium Webdriver sendKeys enters values in IE11 32 bit but then removes it

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11, webdriverwait, iedriverserver

I have to enter text in a input box in a selenium test in java. I am using below code to do that and it enters the characters but then deletes it:

```
WebElement depart=webControls.getDriver().findElement(By.id("oneWayFlight_fromLocation"));((JavascriptExecutor) webControls.getDriver()).executeScript("document.getElementById('oneWayFlight_fromLocation').value='JFK'");
```

OR

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webControls.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].value='JFK';",depart);
```

OR

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webControls.getDriver()).executeScript(String.format("document.getElementById('oneWayFlight_fromLocation').value='JFK';","JFK"));
```

Here is the text field:

```
<input id="oneWayFlight_fromLocation" type="text" class="InputText-control hasError hasIcon" name="oneWayFlight_fromLocation" placeholder="From" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

I following setup:

1. Windows 10 64 bit
2. IE11 32 bit
3. IE DriverServer 32 bit
4. Protection mode is off for all
5. nativeEvents is false
6. REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS  is true
7. 64 bit process in unchecked in Advance Security

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the *FROM* and *TO* field using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you don't have to resort to [JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089)'s [`executeScript()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394478/what-is-the-return-type-of-executescript-method-of-javascriptexecutor/55394803#55394803) method. Instead you can use the much proven and efficient `sendKeys()` method inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebDriver driver =  new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.amextravel.com/flight-searches");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()='One Way']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#oneWayFlight_fromLocation"))).sendKeys("JFK");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebDriver driver =  new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.amextravel.com/flight-searches");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()='One Way']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='oneWayFlight_fromLocation']"))).sendKeys("JFK");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: amextravel]

Comment: Thanks Debanjan. I am seeing that only the last character 'K' is entered in the From text field and then it disappears?

Comment: @SnehTripathi Can you tweak the settings, like `Protected mode` to `checked` for all zones, `nativeEvents` to `true` and retest?

Comment: Can you check the xpath? There was an error which I have corrected just now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to make a test with Sendkeys(). I try to test it on my side and it works without any issue.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

               System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\D drive backup\\selenium web drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");  
               WebDriver browser = new InternetExplorerDriver();

               browser.get("https://www.amextravel.com/flight-searches");
               browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

               WebElement txtbox1=browser.findElement(By.name("oneWayFlight_fromLocation"));
               txtbox1.sendKeys("ABC");

               WebElement txtbox2 = browser.findElement(By.name("oneWayFlight_toLocation"));    
               txtbox2.sendKeys("xyz");
     }
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can modify the code to work as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I am seeing that only the last character 'K' is entered in the From text field and then it disappears?