# How to access text in a website using Java Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, textnode

How to access text in a website using Java Selenium?

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Can someone explain to me how to access the demouser and email id using java selenium in the above picture

https://phptravels.com/demo this is the website im working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you should be able to get these values from those elements values.
I.e. you can get the `email` input value with this:

```java
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.strong[text()='Email']]"));
String innerEmailvalue = email.getAttribute("value");
```

The same for the second element

Comment: i am just getting null for the above recomended solution

Comment: OK, but you are correctly getting the `email` WebElement? It's not a null etc?

Comment: https://phptravels.com/demo this is the website i'm dealing with im supposed to read all the email is and passwords for all types of users

Comment: Moment, have you tried to extract the text with `email.getText()` ?

Comment: yes im still getting null value

Answer (score 0):

The text **demouser** is within a *Text Node* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the *`visibilityOfElementLocated()`* and using [executeScript()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394478/what-is-the-return-type-of-executescript-method-of-javascriptexecutor/55394803#55394803) from [**JavascriptExecutor**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//strong[text()='Password']//ancestor::div[1]")));
String myText = (String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", myElement);
System.out.println(myText);
```

In a single line:

```
System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//strong[text()='Password']//ancestor::div[1]")))));
```