# executeScript() method for scrolling throws error as null cannot create object using Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrollview, execute-script

For scrolling through a section, I wrote below code:

```
JavaScriptExecutor js= (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript (scroll code);
```

but here executeSctipt method is autosuggested like:

```
js.executeScript(null,args)
```

and it throw error as null cannot create object. The actual argument (scroll code) is working as expected in the console.

It should be displayed as:

```
js.executeScript(arg0,arg1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following Eclipse version:

```
Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112
```

The perfect suggestions are observed:

[image: executeScript]

Though selecting the suggested option defaults to *`null`* and *`args`* but the tooltip still continues to suggest the actual argument types.

[image: executeScriptNULL]

You can use the [`executeScript()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55394803/7429447) method accordingly:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", webElement);
```

---

### Refrences

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [What is JavaScriptExecutor in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52698089/7429447)
- [What does arguments[0] and arguments[1] mean when using executeScript method from JavascriptExecutor interface through Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873090/7429447)