# Selenium (Python) - clicking button element but not redirecting page to target link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button

I'm testing a web UI using Selenium in Python. I've come to a test case where a button should be redirected to another page after clicking.

However, every time the code executes without any exceptions but still the page is not being redirected. I'm sure that the button gets clicked correctly, as the button animation and mouse cursor changes.

I tried with direct click method and also Javascript click method

```
`sign_in = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='btn btn-primary-blue']")
 sign_in.click()
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", sign_in)`
```

and the element

```
`<div class="editorial-hero-banner--footer pb-35 pb-sm-0"><div class="SSOLogin__Container"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-blue">Sign in / Register</button></div></div>
    <div class="SSOLogin__Container"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-blue">Sign in / Register</button></div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-blue">Sign in / Register</button>`
```

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for this. We need more information! I copied your code and it worked for me. But since I didn't have the full page I had to add `onclick="alert(1)"` to check if clicking the button works.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<div class="editorial-hero-banner--footer pb-35 pb-sm-0">
    <div class="SSOLogin__Container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-blue">Sign in / Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The <kbd>Sign in / Register</kbd> element is a dynamic element.

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.SSOLogin__Container > button.btn.btn-primary-blue"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary-blue'][starts-with(., 'Sign in') and contains(., 'Register')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can use the [executeScript()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55394803/7429447) method from [***JavascriptExecutor***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52698089/7429447) as follows:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.SSOLogin__Container > button.btn.btn-primary-blue"))))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary-blue'][starts-with(., 'Sign in') and contains(., 'Register')]"))))
  ```

Comment: Tried this even the issue is the same, the executes without any errors but is not redirected to another page

Comment: Hello thanks, buddy, but there is no change in trying this also

Comment: Hello Buddy, 
print(sign_in.is_displayed())
print(sign_in.is_selected())
print(sign_in.is_enabled())
tried these in sequence to test but returned as
True

Comment: Hello Buddy, 
print(sign_in.is_displayed())
print(sign_in.is_selected())
print(sign_in.is_enabled())
tried these in sequence to test but returned as
True
False
True